# Query serialized array of Time objects and return ActiveRecord::Relation objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm storing `Time` objects in a serialized array, defined like this:

```
Class Message < ApplicationRecord
  serialize :sent_at, Array
end
```

Is there any way to do a time comparison query on that array, and returning a collection of `ActiveRecord::Relation` objects?

E.g. "return all Message objects that has time objects in the `sent_at` attribute that are older than `Time.now`".

Doing this with `.select` returns an array and I'd like if possible to keep the ActiveRecord::Relation objects.